# UWP NavigationMenu with only C# source code

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, desktop-application, fluent-design

#### Introduction

When I look at tutorials on how to develop a navigation menu in UWP design, **all** **I** **see** is **XAML** code being used.

#### Problem

I can't find any other video tutorials on how to develop a navigation menu in C# code **only**.

#### Question

How can I develop this navigation ([See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xua1y.png)) menu using only **C#**?

[Screenshot of the Navigationmenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xua1y.png)

Comment: Hi bozut! Your question is quite broad and it hard to answer. Can you review the tutorial from Microsoft, do some trial example and share your work and challenges you see trying it?
https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/windows/uwp/design/basics/xaml-basics-ui

Answer (score 0):

The use of Xaml files is to separate the UI and the code. Once the UI code is mixed with logic code, the app will become very bloated and difficult to maintain.

So it is more convenient to use the XAML code design. If you do want to do this by code-behind, please refer to the following code.

```
NavigationView navigationView = new NavigationView();           
var Item1 = new NavigationViewItem() { Content = "Item1", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Download) };
var Item1 = new NavigationViewItem() { Content = "Item2", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Page) }; 
navigationView .MenuItems.Add(Item1);
navigationView .MenuItems.Add(Item2);                       
MyGrid.Children.Add(navigationView );
```